# external volumes partitioning mount point

Tags: partitioning, ram, swap, disk

When creating an external volume for personal use (apart from Home) which mount point shall it start from? */* or */home* or */usr*? Or what?
It's equivalent to the *D* drive at windows.
And if I put 9 GB swap area for a 4 GB Ram will it be used or is it too much?
.. thank you

Comment: you can put it wherever you want but keep in mind the location will often determine the permissions on the mount point. if you want to use it for data storage. the best spot would be a folder in your home directory ( /home/username/) for easy access.

Comment: a common place is /mnt/(whatever); but you can use whatever you want.  i like /(whatever) for my personal machines as it means i have less to type.  as for swap space; what you use it for will determine the right space.  if you have a sdd (esp. some times) swap will wear it out faster so reduce swappiness if you want a longer life; but 9gb will likely allow hibernate (if you use it; ie. 4gb + whatever you were using @ the moment you hibernate).

Comment: there is no mount/whatever there is :

Comment: / , /boot, /home, /tmp , /usr. /var, /srv /opt, /usr/local

Comment: What do you mean, there is no mount? Do you mean that the partition on your external drive is not mounted? You can get more detailed help, if you run the command `sudo lsblk -f ` in a terminal window (when the external drive is connected), and edit your original question to post your answer. Indent each line four spaces to render is a `code`. (You can copy and paste from the terminal window to the editing box here at AskUbuntu.)

Comment: i am still installing it. i need to assign a mounting point for the extended space in the drive . it's not for the operating system .. its not removable . its in my hard disk just other than root, home or swap .. what mounting point cn i assign it to so i can use it as space later ? i can't leave it without mounting point it said if i left it so it will act as though it doesn't exist

Comment: You can do it according to my answer. A good convention is to create mount points in `/mnt`. Create a name you like, for example `/mnt/sd1`, and use that mount point in the line that you add into `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: The standard way is to create some directory in `/media` and mount it there.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `/media` is intended for automounting external drives, `/mnt` is intended for manual setting the system to mount, for example via `/etc/fstab`. But the end user is free to create mountpoints at both locations, and at other locations too.

Answer (score 2):

In many cases Ubuntu will create a mount point automatically and mount the partition(s) on the external drive.

If this is not the case, I suggest that you create a mountpoint / mountpoints and use them manually or via a line in the file `/etc/fstab`, for example

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/sd1
```

You should *not* mount the swap partition. It should be 'swapped on', also automatically via a line in `/etc/fstab`. If you want hibernation, 5 GB should be enough (slightly more than RAM in the same units, GiB). Otherwise I think 1 GB or 2 GB swap is enough.

Examples with template lines from my file `/etc/fstab`,

*Partition in **internal** drive:*

```
UUID=5ece9189-9a67-8176-a7ae-281890f4e3f6  /mnt/sd1    ext4    defaults 0       2
```

*Partition in **external** drive, not always connected:*

```
UUID=5ece9189-9a67-8176-a7ae-281890f4e3f6  /mnt/sd1    ext4    defaults,noauto 0       2
```

In this case you have to mount the drive manually (because of `noauto`).

*Swap:*

```
UUID=b260d471-caf5-37e3-b731-4b895c66a868 none         swap    sw              0       0
```

You can find the UUIDs with the command `blkid`.

Comment: I don't recommend to mount anything permanently to /mnt.